# Can't connect wordpress to mariadb (docker)

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have two containers, one for mariadb and the other for wordpress.

I'm using this configuration for mariadb:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

And this for wordpress

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  # Wordpress
  myWordpress:
    image: wordpress:php8.1
    container_name: myWordpress
    hostname: myWordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: [ './data:/var/www/html' ]
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mariadb
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER="${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}"
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD="${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}"
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME="${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}"
    networks:
      - web
networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

I already created the network `web` and logged in mysql root , created the database & user and executed this command: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wp_db.* TO 'wp_user'@'%';`.

Then I logged in mysql using that user and its password.

```bash
docker exec -it mariadb bash
mysql -u wp_user -pMyPassword
# Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
# ...
```

The issue appears when I visit wordpress, I see this message:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '"wp_user"'@'172.16.32.5' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1753
Access denied for user '"wp_user"'@'172.16.32.5' (using password: YES)
```

I feel that the problem is in `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST` variable, I pointed it to mariadb container name, I also tried pointing it to `localhost` since both containers share the same network `web`, but his didn't work either, and the same exact error message appeared.

Comment: Wait, why do you have 2 docker-compose files?.. `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST` should be set to db container name (`mariadb`), but for this to work you need two services in one compose file. It is possible to make them interact with separate files, but it's more difficult and I don't see any reason to do so. (or explain why it is desired, otherwise [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) arises)

Comment: @SUTerliakov , I made it like this so I can have only one mariadb server, and any number of containers can connect to their databases using that mariadb container.
Let me know if there's another way around it

Comment: Ough, I missed this initially: you have `wp_user` (and probably password too) quoted. If you're using `.env` file, values there should be set without quotes.

Comment: Yup, they are set without quotes.

I think I need some basic script to test connection to that database, I want to make sure that my setup is working

Comment: You log line (`Access denied for user '"wp_user"'@'172.16.32.5'`) says the opposite: you have them quoted somewhere.

Comment: Those are not in .env file, but they are in docker-compose file : `- WORDPRESS_DB_USER="${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}"` , I removed them, but the issue still exists, and the quotation marks are also there in logs.
Wait, sorry, that log line is old, I'm going to test it again

Comment: I tested it again using direct values instead of environment variables, but it won't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One month later, I went back to this issue and tried putting environment variables in quotes, it worked as expected.

So instead of:

```
  - WORDPRESS_DB_USER="${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}"
```

It should be

```
  - "WORDPRESS_DB_USER=${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}"
```